# How do I update a specific column value for all tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create procedure change_ardivisionno
@CustomerNo nvarchar(7),@table_name varchar(40)

AS
Begin
SET NOCOUNT ON
Update @table_name
SET ARDivisionNo = '21'
where @CustomerNo = (select customerno from mas_abc.dbo.customerlist)
and @table_name = (select tablename from table_list)
END
```

I'm trying to update `ARDisivionNo` (`ARDivisionno` is the column name) value set to 21 in all tables of the database where `customerno` is the list of customers stored in customer list table.

I'm trying to create this procedure but I keep getting the error:

> *Must declare the table variable "@table_name".*

Comment: is @table_name a table variable? http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Comment: table_name is the is the list of tables names stored in table_list

Comment: How are `customerlist` and the individual tables related? Does each table have a `CustomerNo` column?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, except I don't understand how your current `WHERE` clause is supposed to limit the update to a set of rows in the target table. Right now it seems like it will update the entire table; I suspect there is a join condition missing.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'UPDATE t
  SET ARDivisionNo = ''21''
  FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(tablename) + ' AS t
  INNER JOIN mas_abc.dbo.customerlist AS c
  ON c.customerno = @CustomerNo;';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Cust NVARCHAR(7)', @CustomerNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically create the SQL to execute, as the tableName can't be a String variable.

See [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

```
declare @DBName varchar(40); 
set @DBName = 'AdventureWorks2012';
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          N'SELECT * FROM '+@DBName+'.HumanResources.Employee 
          WHERE BusinessEntityID = @level',
          N'@level tinyint',
          @level = 109;
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I do, the URL at least goes to the correct place.